# Visual studio 2010 + MySQL + entity framework

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to connect MySQL database by using entity framework. I have my VB.net code below:

```
    Dim context As sql688249Entities = New sql688249Entities()
    Dim nsv As sinhvien = New sinhvien()
    nsv.MSSV = Int(234)
    nsv.Hoten = "Thanh"
    nsv.Diachi = "Phu Yen"
    context.sinhviens.AddObject(nsv)
    context.SaveChanges()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = context.sinhviens
```

But it doesn't work. If I remove `context.Savechanges()` it has no problem. I don't understand why I cannot insert a record into database.

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? What is the current outcome, and what is the expected outcome?

Comment: It doesn't work means It has error so cannot run. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The class that your trying to add has a `Create...` method for building the record. Make sure you are increasing the primary key field for the table as well.

```
Using context As sql688249Entities = New sql688249Entities()
  Dim id As Integer = 1 ' get the last id or use this default
  Dim lastOne = context.sinhviens.OrderByDescending(Function(s) s s.MSSV).FirstOrDefault
  If lastOne IsNot Nothing Then
    id = lastOne.MSSV + 1 ' add one to have a valid next id
  End If
  Dim nsv As sinhvien = sinhvien.Createsinhvien(id, "Thanh", "Phu Yen")
  context.sinhviens.AddObject(nsv)
  DataGridView1.DataSource = context.sinhviens
  context.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you so much but It still has error. UpdateException was unhandled

Comment: Right, what does it say? Use a `Try/Catch` if you need to get the details.

Comment: It says: an error occurred while updating the entries

Comment: There is more info keep digging. Look at my example again for poss fix.

Comment: Is the `{id field}` in my example the `MSSV` field?

Comment: But in mysql database, sinhvien is an empty table.There is no problem if I use msqlconnetion to insert, update, delete record.

Comment: How many fields are there? What is the primary key for the table?

Comment: Are you sure the `context` is connecting to the database?

Comment: I am sure the context is connecting because the command DataGridView1.DataSource = context.sinhviens can display all data in the table sinhvien. I also added context.connection.open. In sinhvien, there are 3 fields and MSSV is primary key.

Comment: I still there is more info in the error object that would help us out. From your fields there does not seem to be foreign key constraint problem - can you confirm that?

Comment: in database just has a single table sinhvien that has 3 fields. MSS is integer, Hoten and Diachi are text. There is no foreign key constraint. :((

Comment: When add data source, there is a message: The table/view 'def.sql688249.sinhvien' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.

Comment: Thank you, OneFineDay. I can solve my problem. I didnt know why the first time there is no primary key. I remove model and add data again and it work.

Comment: Glad it is working for you. Yes EF has to have a primary key for all tables.